# what happens exactly in the following code

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
int i=10;
printf("%d\n",i);
i++;
}
}
```

Why it gives the answer 10
                        10
                        10
                        10
                        10
                        10

Instead if we use this code it gives a problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
int i=10;
printf("%d\n",i);
i++;
}
}
```

Please explain what happens exactly in both cases. I mean how compiler works in these cases.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: The compiler works exactly the same. It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: yeah for the 2nd code it shows i has already been declared in the for loop as the loop variable and hence cannot be declared inside but in the first case it gives the given output.

Comment: In the first case it prints 10 6 times but in the next case it gives the error that i has already been declared as the loop varible and cannot be decared again.What is the difference between the two codes and why such distinct result.Has it got something to do with the memory allocation of i.

Comment: A variable introduced in the `for` loop is the same as if it had been introduced in the *body* of the for loop.

Comment: Yeah dat should be it.But it is not.That is my question.Just compile the code once and see what you guys get.

Comment: @vaibhav: Yes, it does.

Comment: vaibhav int can be written inside the loop I can declare any other variable inside the loop.Why not.But logically i shouldn't be allowed to be declared inside but in the first case it allows.My question is why??

Comment: Is your code `C` or `C++`? Tag is `C`. In `C99` it [compiles well](http://ideone.com/I409yv). In older versions of `C`, `for(int i...)` won't compile.

Answer (score 3):

In the first case,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<=5;i++)
   {
      int i=10; // This shadows the previous i
      printf("%d\n",i);
      i++;
   }
}
```

In the second case,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
   {
      int i=10; // This is a problem because the previous i
                // is in the same scope as this i.
      printf("%d\n",i);
      i++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block there are actually two scopes, and the `i` declared in each scope is a *different* variable.

Consider this equivalent code, with *different* variable names to avoid/show the confusion with the second declaration shadowing the first.

```
// outer scope
int i;
for(i=0;i<=5;i++)      // loops 5 times, only increments i here
{
  // inner scope
  int J=10;            // always assigns 10 to J before print
  printf("%d\n",J);
  J++;                 // no effect on i
}
```

As for the second case, a variable declared in the `for` loop *initialization* section is declared in the same scope as the *body* of the for loop:

```
// Same as declaring i in the inner scope ..
for(int i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
   // .. so this is a compiler error because i is
   // already declared this in scope.
   int i=10;
}
```

That is, the compile treats the second case about like..

```
int i=0;
int i=10; // but this redeclaration is invalid
```

.. and KABOOM!